# Capturing "control" keydown press event in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, dom-events

I'm trying to figure out when the user presses the <kbd>control</kbd> key in an HTML page using JavaScript.

In the following code "CTRL UP" will appear as expected, but "CTRL DOWN" will only appear if I *also* press another key, e.g. <kbd>shift</kbd>.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
  // Bind to both command (for Mac) and control (for Win/Linux)
  if (event.ctrlKey) {
    console.log("CTRL UP");
  }
}, false);

window.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
  // Bind to both command (for Mac) and control (for Win/Linux)
  if (event.ctrlKey) {
    console.log("CTRL DOWN");
  }
}, false);

</script>
</head>
<body>
Ctrl Demo
</body>
</html>
```

Is there any way to get the "CTRL DOWN" key event to work as expected, when <kbd>ctrl</kbd> is pressed and held down by itself?

NOTE: I'm trying to get this to work in a Google Chrome extension, so using Chrome specific APIs or tricks to make this work is completely fine. I'm using Google Chrome 15.0.874.83 beta on Ubuntu.

Comment: If there is some program running that has listener for this key on OS level then it won't fire in js.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Your code works for me, as does the following jQuery. (Chrome)

```
$(window).keydown(function(e){
    if (e.ctrlKey)
        console.log('Control Down');
});
```

Using alert is a little awkward because it blocks the process and you won't see any key state changes that occur while the dialog is up. I recommend using console.info/log/debug

Comment: Not sure what to say, it's not working for me.  Holding down control and _no_ other key only produces "CTRL UP" messages in the log.

Comment: This is not the correct answer.  See the one below.

Answer (score 11):

If you just want to detect the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key being pressed on its own, the following will work (although bear in mind that `addEventListener` is not supported in IE < 9, where you'd need to use `attachEvent` or `onkeydown` instead):

```
window.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
    // Bind to both command (for Mac) and control (for Win/Linux)
    if (event.keyCode == 17) {
        alert("Ctrl");
    }
}, false);
```