# Javascript capturing keydown

Tags: javascript

I have a form with many fields and when the user does a "double Enter" in any of the fields `doSomething()` should happen.

The code below basically works ok, apart from the fact that `doSomething()` gets called as many times as there are characters in that field. It should only be called once, while if I put "ABC" in the field, `doSomething()` gets called 3X. It only needs to be called once after 2X Enter, regardless of what was entered in the field.

I (kind of) understand why it's happening (keydown was called 3 times) but have no idea how to fix it. Do I need to `unbind` something? Resetting the counter to `0` when `e.keyCode` isn't `13` doesn't seem to make a difference.

EDIT - http://jsfiddle.net/hzr8cezn/ - I'm using 2X SPACE bar character to test since Enter tries to submit the form on jsfiddle. Hit 2X space (in Chrome) and check your console

```
$("#dynamicFields").on('keydown', 'input', function(e) {
        var counter = 0
        var field = $(this)
        field.keydown(function (e) {
            if(e.keyCode == 13) {
                counter++;
                if(counter == 2) {
                    console.log('twice!')
                    doSomething()
                } 
            }
            else {
                 counter = 0
            }
        })
    })
```

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle for this?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7801174/capturing-control-keydown-press-event-in-javascript and remember that GIYF

Comment: Fiddle added. Use SPACE instead of ENTER key

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are attaching to the "keydown" event twice, once using `on()` and the other using `keydown()`. You only need to do this once.

Since you are tracking the counter per element, you can use a [`data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) call to track it on the element itself.

```
// init counter to 0
$("#dynamicFields input").data('counter',0);

// bind to keypress event
$("#dynamicFields").on('keydown', 'input', function(e) {
    // the input field
    var $field = $(this);
    // enter key?
    if ( e.keyCode == 13 ){
        // how many times?
        var counter = $field.data('counter');
        // increment it
        $field.data('counter',++counter);
        // do the stuff
        if ( counter >= 2 ){
            alert('well, you did it.');
        }
    } else {
        // reset
        $field.data('counter',0);
    }
})
```

See it working in this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/52zpy6rv/1/).